# update image profile with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Well what I want to do is to update image profile picture of the user with jquery from database but it does not pull out the source of image from db.please tell me where I'm wrong.

here is my code

```
include('../inc/config.inc.php');
$userSession = @$_SESSION["utente"];
    $verificaPic = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT pic_profilo FROM users WHERE username='$userSession'");
    $row_pic = mysqli_fetch_array($verificaPic, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $pic = $row_pic["pic_profilo"];

        if($row_pic["pic_profilo"] !== ""){
            echo "<img src='$pic' class='img-polaroid'>";
        }else{
            echo '<img src="img/defaultuser.png" class="img-polaroid">';
        }
```

and this is my jquery call

```
   JQ(function($) {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("/ajax/DataProfilo.php",
           function(data) {
             $("#picprofilo").html(data); //  2pm
           });
       }, 100);//1000-1 sec 
});
```

Comment: What exactly is it pulling from the database? Is it a URL to the new image or a `blob` with the image itself?

Comment: GET http://localhost/class=%22img-polaroid%22 403 (Forbidden) jquery-1.10.1.min.js:5 i update the jqeury code please can you help me?

Comment: I'd like to, but I cannot until you answer my question.

Comment: its not pull out nothing from db

Comment: if i set echo '<img src="$pic" class="img-polaroid">'; say localhost/$pic 404 not found... and if i put echo '<img src="'.$pic.'" class="img-polaroid">'; dont return errors but return blank like this <img src="" class="img-polaroid">

Comment: change `mysqli_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_row`

Comment: nothing....  its return blank

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then the code below is the **`DataProfilo.php`** script, correct? Please make the few minor changes in this code and show me what the result of the AJAX call is from the *console*. I also need to see the original HTML markup showing what `#picprofilo` is.

**PHP**

```
include('../inc/config.inc.php');
$userSession = @$_SESSION["utente"];
$q = "SELECT pic_profilo FROM users WHERE username='" . $userSession . "'"; // **add this line of code**
echo $q."\n";
$verificaPic = mysqli_query($db,$q); // **change this line of code!!**
$row_pic = mysqli_fetch_assoc($verificaPic);
$pic = $row_pic["pic_profilo"];
if (!empty($row_pic["pic_profilo"])) {
    echo "<img src='$pic' class='img-polaroid'>";
} else {
    echo "<img src='img/defaultuser.png' class='img-polaroid'>";
}
```

**jQuery**

```
JQ(function($) {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("/ajax/DataProfilo.php",
            function(data) {
                $("#picprofilo").html(data);
                console.log(data);
            });
        }, 100);//1000-1 sec 
});
```

Comment: in console does not print nothing,and on page shows up defaultimage,dont fetch from db

Comment: Where are you defining `$db` for the connection to the database?

Comment: $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "***");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("CnxF: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} i iserted on the same page on DataProfilo.php but stil nothing man:(

Comment: Is that in the `config.inc.php` file? Can you also add it to the DataProfilo.php file just below the include?

Comment: i just added but still nothing,i use bootstrap tabs for html,and stil show default image on folder img/default.png not the link from db

Comment: You need to verify that your query works outside of the PHP script.

Comment: Please note changes in the PHP script and try them.

Comment: pfff it whas from DataProfilo.php ....the session it was not started and the image linked must be to ../$row_pic["pic_profilo"]; sily me:))